# How to change default google maps zoom level when user search by entering zip code?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a simple google maps with search box capability in which a user can search any city, address, country or zip code and after hitting enter, the zoom level of the map will take you there. Depending on what user searched, zoom level is decided by google map functions.

Now when a user search for a city, say Houston, TX. Google maps zoom down to some level where one can see Houston city at the center of the map. But when a user searches for a particular ZIP code in Houston city, google maps zooms in further to display only that area which comes under the bounds of ZIP code entered. How can I change this default behavior of zoom levels and bounds so that when a user enters ZIP code, google maps find the related city and display that city only (not the zoomed in area of ZIP code).

I am not attaching any code as one can visualize this simply on google maps.

Comment: Would the downvoter tell me why did he downvote ? I searched thoroughly and could not find a question which covered this issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Geocode the ZIP code.
2. Reverse geocode the resulting coordinates, select the result that includes the city name.
3. Geocode the city name, use the bounds of the response to adjust the zoom of the map.

Comment: Thanks. This helps a lot. I kind of had this approach in mind but I was wondering if there is any other shorter approach where one can style the bounds or something.